# Craft 3: Upload user photo from front end

Tags: users, craft3, upload

How do I allow logged in users to change their user photo on the front end in Craft 3?

I am creating an "Edit Profile" page and I followed the answer to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/allow-user-to-change-or-delete-their-photo-for-their-profile-from-the-front-end) for Craft 2 to create a form updating to Craft 3 syntax where necessary (code below). When I submit the form, the text/textarea fields get updated, but the image does not. Can anyone point me in the direction as to how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

```
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrfInput() }}

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
        {{ redirectInput('users') }}

        {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% endmacro %}

        {% from _self import errorList %}

        <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

        {% if currentUser.getPhoto != '' %}
            <img src="{{ currentUser.getPhoto.getUrl }}" alt=""><br>
        {% endif %}
        <input type="file" id="userPhoto" name="userPhoto" value="Upload">

        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}"><br>

        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" value="{{ currentUser.lastName }}"><br>

        <label for="bio">Bio</label>
        <textarea id="bio" name="fields[bio]">{{ currentUser.bio }}</textarea>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password"><br>

        {% if account is defined %}
            {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
        {% endif %}

        <input type="submit" value="Save Profile">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name used for the user photo has changed to `photo`, so the bare minimum change to make this work is modifying
`<input type="file" id="userPhoto" name="userPhoto" value="Upload">`
to be
`<input type="file" id="userPhoto" name="photo" value="Upload">`

You'll probably want to use transforms, when outputting that image, too.

Also, I'd stick with `currentUser.photo` or `currentUser.getPhoto()`, instead of using a hybrid `currentPhoto.getPhoto`, but that might just be me.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Did you find that in the documentation? I couldn't seem to find it there.

Comment: I just took a short trip through Craft's code to see what field name it's looking for.