# Deleting a user's profile photo via frontend in Craft3

Tags: assets, users, user-profile

I am having the hardest time allowing a user to delete their profile photo with Craft3. I have tried to follow this thread's answers : [Allow user to change or delete their photo for their profile from the front end](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/allow-user-to-change-or-delete-their-photo-for-their-profile-from-the-front-end). But it is not working. I guess because some stuff has changed since Craft2.

Here is my twig code :

```
<div class="profile-image">
    {% if isEditable %}
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            {{ csrfInput() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
            {{ redirectInput('profil/'~currentUser.id) }}
            <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

            {% macro errorList(errors) %}
                {% if errors %}
                    <ul class="errors">
                        {% for error in errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endmacro %}

            {% from _self import errorList %}

            <input type="hidden" name="deleteUserPhoto" id="deleteUserPhotoInput" value="">
            {% if account is defined %}{{ errorList(account.getErrors('deleteUserPhoto')) }}{% endif %}

            <div>
                <a class="change-profile-photo-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <img class="circle" src="{{ user.getThumbUrl(250) }}"
                         alt="{{ user.friendlyName }}"/>
                    <div class="overlay waves-effect waves-light waves-circle">
                        <span>Modifier ma photo de profil</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <input id="profilePhotoInput" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
        </form>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);"
           class="delete-profile-photo-btn btn btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light coriandr-red tooltipped"
           data-position="bottom" data-delay="500" data-tooltip="Supprimer ma photo de profil"><i
                    class="material-icons">delete</i></a>

    {% else %}
        <img class="circle" src="{{ user.getThumbUrl(250) }}" alt="{{ user.friendlyName }}"/>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

And the Javascript code :

```
$('.delete-profile-photo-btn').on('click', function () {
    var deleteUserPhotoInput = $("#deleteUserPhotoInput");
    deleteUserPhotoInput.val('1');
    deleteUserPhotoInput.parents("form").submit();
});
```

With this code, I get no errors, and the profile image doesn't delete.

I then decided to try and reverse engineer the admin panel and see how it was done there. I came up with the following form :

```
<form id="deleteUserPhotoForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/delete-user-photo">
    {{ redirectInput('profil/'~currentUser.id) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
</form>
```

And the Javascript :

```
var form = $('#deleteUserPhotoForm');

var data = form.serialize();
userFormAjaxCall(data, function (status, resp, xhr) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(resp);
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

With this code, it seems to work, but I get this error message (not sure what the equivalent in english is).

> Impossible de trouver le modèle “users/_photo”

What is the cleanest and simplest way I can allow a user to delete their profile photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input name has changed from "deleteUserPhoto" to "deletePhoto" in Craft 3.

Here is my updated working Twig code if anyone needs it :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
    {{ redirectInput('profil/'~currentUser.id) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    <input type="hidden" name="deletePhoto" id="deleteUserPhotoInput" value="">

    <input id="profilePhotoInput" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

And my Javascript code :

```
$('.delete-profile-photo-btn').on('click', function () {
    var deleteUserPhotoInput = $("#deleteUserPhotoInput");
    deleteUserPhotoInput.val('1');
    deleteUserPhotoInput.parents("form").submit();
});
```